# Add metadata to image using GD

Tags: php, image, gd

I have image uploaded on the server in jpg format, everytime browser request a image if image not exist in webp i resize and conver image into webp format.

Since here everything work fine but new converted image (webp) is missing metadata like author, copyright, comment .... from original image.

Is there any way to add medatata from original image to converted (webp) image during resizing or converting ?

this is my code

```
    $image = new Image(DIR_IMAGE . $old_image);
    $image->resize($width, $height);
    $image->save_webp(DIR_IMAGE . $new_image_webp, $quality);

    public function resize($width = 0, $height = 0, $default = '') {
    if (!$this->info['width'] || !$this->info['height']) {
        return;
    }
    $xpos = 0;
    $ypos = 0;
    $scale = 1;

    $scale_w = $width / $this->info['width'];
    $scale_h = $height / $this->info['height'];

    if ($default == 'w') {
        $scale = $scale_w;
    } elseif ($default == 'h') {
        $scale = $scale_h;
    } else {
        $scale = min($scale_w, $scale_h);
    }

    if ($scale == 1 && $scale_h == $scale_w && $this->info['mime'] != 'image/png') {
        return;
    }

    $new_width = (int)($this->info['width'] * $scale);
    $new_height = (int)($this->info['height'] * $scale);
    $xpos = (int)(($width - $new_width) / 2);
    $ypos = (int)(($height - $new_height) / 2);

    $image_old = $this->image;
    $this->image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

    if (isset($this->info['mime']) && $this->info['mime'] == 'image/png') {
        imagealphablending($this->image, false);
        imagesavealpha($this->image, true);
        $background = imagecolorallocatealpha($this->image, 255, 255, 255, 127);
        imagecolortransparent($this->image, $background);
    } else {
        $background = imagecolorallocate($this->image, 255, 255, 255);
    }

    imagefilledrectangle($this->image, 0, 0, $width, $height, $background);

    imagecopyresampled($this->image, $image_old, $xpos, $ypos, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $this->info['width'], $this->info['height']);
    imagedestroy($image_old);

    $this->info['width']  = $width;
    $this->info['height'] = $height;
}

    public function save_webp($file, $quality = 40) {
    if (is_resource($this->image)) {
        imagewebp($this->image, $file, $quality);
        imagedestroy($this->image);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you use **IMagick** it will carry forward EXIF and other netadata on resizing.

Comment: @MarkSetchell can you give me some example with IMagick ? is also work for webp images?

Comment: There's a whole website full here http://www.rubblewebs.co.uk/imagick/functions/functions.php?page=16#Resize_image

Comment: Another here https://phpimagick.com

Comment: @MarkSetchell sorry dude i mean about set metadata like author, copyright...  i tried this one https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.setimageproperty.php but is aywas return  syntax error, unexpected ''Imagick'' in $image->setImageProperty('Exif:Make', 'Imagick');

Comment: Your question says the metadata from the original is missing. Did you try loading an image with metadata, resize and save?